# How to have a custom IIS port number in Azure VM?

Tags: windows, azure, iis, virtual-machine

I followed the instructions to setup IIS in Azure VM. It works.

But unlike our own PC, the VM doesn't have the IIS Manager to configure the port number. By default it is port 80, I want to change it to 1234, so my website can be accessed at: http://mysite.cloudapp.com:1234

How to achieve this?

P.S.: I am aware that I would need to create a new endpoint. But how it maps the port 1234 to the default 80? (Or am I able to change to 1234 from 80?).

**EDIT:**

Shame on me. I type from window start and could not locate the "IIS Manager".

Instead, it could be opened from the "`Server Manager->IIS->(click your server)->Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install IIS manager.

Make sure that the IIS Management Console is enabled through via Control Panel -> Programs and Features. From Server Manager, click Add roles and features and follow the prompts.

Comment: to add to this, you need to open up port 1234 on the NSG

Comment: Thanks for mentioning "Server Manager". From there it has the IIS Tab which we can open the IIS Manager!